# How to return milliseconds from beginning of day from Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, milliseconds

I want to be able to bypass this code (`getTimeInMillis()` in `Calendar` class) and simply return the zero hour, minutes, and seconds from a specific date. Time is not set because it was built as a "Date" only now. So right now my code is always hitting this and giving me an "offset." This is even after doing below:

```java
this.getEventDate().set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

I want to return milliseconds as `long`. Right now it uses `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` which calculates a time as its not originally on the date object.

Is there a method out there to handle this?

Comment: This is barely comprehensible but what I got from it is this: Find the number of milliseconds between Jan 1, 1970, and midnight on a specified date in a specified time zone. Is that what you want? Are you starting from a date represented as a character string, or a `java.util.Date` instance?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). To get the count of milliseconds since midnight use `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY)`. At 8:16 PM in my time zone it returned 73 026 362.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static long millisSinceStartOfToday() {
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    // reset hour, minutes, seconds and millis
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    
    return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime().getTime());
}
```

Comment: Some dates in some time zones start at a time other than 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question could use a rewrite for clarity. But I’ll take a guess at what you are asking.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## First moment of the day

You seem to be asking to determine the first moment of the day.

Understand that some dates in some time zones do not start at 00:00:00. So let *java.time* determine the first moment.

Here is an example. In Iran, the day of “Spring Ahead” in Daylight Saving Time starts at the stroke of midnight. The clock jumps to 1 AM. So the hour of 00:00:00 does not exist.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tehran" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.MARCH, 22 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xlxQMd).

> 2022-03-22T01:00+04:30[Asia/Tehran]

## Count of milliseconds

And you apparently want to get a count of milliseconds from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC by extracting an `Instant`.
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 1647894600000

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of milliseconds from a specified time to 00:00:00 of the day, the following code may help you

```java
final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
final long DAY_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
//`now - (now % DAY_MILLIS)` will get the mill second at 08:00
long dayStart = now - (now % DAY_MILLIS) - DAY_MILLIS / 3;
long millisSinceStartOfToday = now - dayStart;

//in other word
//millisSinceStartOfToday = (now % DAY_MILLIS) + DAY_MILLIS / 3;
```